# Calculating partial values for use in a weighted average

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have a spreadsheet with the following information:

- Column A contains a list of courses (eg Course 1, Course 2, etc)
- Column B contains the number of credits available to each course
- Column C contains the grade expressed as an integer (eg 72, 63, etc)

This information is then sorted by grade, from highest to lowest.

With this information, I need to group the courses into 4 equal groups, based on the number of total credits available, and determine a weighted average for each group. The credits do not, however, always break evenly, meaning some portion of a course may count towards the first weighted average with the remainder of the course counting towards the second weighted average. For example, I might have:

```
        Credits Grade
Course 1    3   75
Course 2    2   75
Course 3    3   72
Course 4    3   72
Course 5    3   72
Course 6    4   70
Course 7    4   67
Course 8    3   67
Course 9    4   63

Total credits: 29
1/4 of total credits: 7.25
```

The first weighted average would therefore use the full 3 credits for Course 1, the full 2 credits for Course 2, and 2.25 of the 3 credits for Course 3. The remaining 0.75 credits of Course 3 would count towards the second weighted average.

I can calculate where the breaks/partial credits go manually (as in the linked image below), as the math isn't difficult. However, I would like to know if there is a function (or series of functions) that can be used to automate the creation of the 4 sections, so that the weighting and average functions can then be done. The closest I've come to an answer is to put the following formula in D3: =IF(SUM($B$2:B3) <B12,B3,B3-(SUM($B$2:B3)-$B$12)) and copying down until the credits become negative. I then transferred the remainder to F, copy and edit the formula for that column and so on. Very time intensive and prone to error, so I'm hoping there is a much more elegant solution.

[image: Screenshot of Excel file with desired end result]

Comment: There's various ways to do the mechanics of what you asked, and I'm surprised that you haven't already gotten some answers.  However, I'm trying to figure out what the result tells you.  It breaks the courses into four intervals of performance and gives an average for each interval.  But how would that information be used or interpreted?

Comment: Thanks for your comment & question. The 4 averages represent 4 grades/marks. The overall purpose of the spreadsheet is to convert American letter grades received for courses taken by exchange students into UK marks (I removed the American letter grade column from the example used above to simplify). Once the converted marks are received for each course taken, the complete set of courses need to be converted into 4 groups of equal weight to produce 4 marks/grades (using weighted averages). These 4 grades are used at the end of studies to generate an overall degree classification (overall grade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are ways to do this very elegantly, but here's an approach that requires the fewest brain cells.  :-)  You already have a solution, but the issue is that it requires a lot of manual work to set it up and to modify it for other cases.  I focused on a template approach to implement what you did manually.  It is easy and fast to create, and can be re-used for other cases without needing to modify it.  This retains a form that is simple to adjust and troubleshoot if your needs change, and to explain to others.

[image: screenshot1]

You'll notice a few differences from your own worksheet.

- There are some hidden columns.  I've added some helper columns to aid in the calculations.
- I reversed the grade and credits columns to make the other column sequences consistent.  This allows copying formulas to build the template without needing to modify them.
- I've inserted a blank line below the headings.  Some of the formulas refer to the previous row, so the formulas in the first row of data need a blank cell above in order to have a single, simple formula that you can use for the whole column.
- Within the Group columns, everything has a value because everything is used in the calculations (including zeros).  If you would prefer blank cells rather than zeros, you can format the cells so that zeros aren't displayed (but they will still be treated as zeros).
- I've moved the averages to a row at the bottom so they can be calculated with a simple formula (actually, it isn't necessary to locate them there, but it's more intuitive to view it that way).  I left an arbitrary number of rows for additional courses.  Make it as many as needed for the maximum number of courses you might encounter.

Here, all of the columns are unhidden:

[image: screenshot2]

By using the same formulas for every row, setting this up is straightforward.  Just enter the formulas in the first row and then copy the row as needed.  There are also just a few different formulas, so replicating them for the different groups will be just copy and paste.  Don't worry if you get some error values temporarily as you build the first row; formulas may be referring to cells where you haven't yet entered the formula.

#### The Formulas

**1/4 Total Credits**

I stuck this down in C21, just to leave an arbitrary number of extra rows so that more courses can be added.  It's calculated using the entire range becuase empty cells don't affect the result, and this lets you have any number of courses.  The formula for a row range of 3-20 of potential courses: `=SUM(C3:C20)/4`

**Cumulative Credits**

To figure out where the credits for each group start and end, there are helper columns that calculate the cumulative credits (or unassigned credits remaining).  These are columns D, H, and L (the 4th group contains everything remaining after the 3rd group, so it saves some calculation).  The formulas, which can be dragged or copied down as needed (fill the potential rows), are:

```
D3:  =SUM(C$3:C3)
H3:  =SUM(G$3:G3)
L3:  =SUM(K$3:K3)
```

You can enter the formula in D3 and then copy it to H3 and L3.

**Unassigned Credits**

These helper columns calculate the credits remaining after each group's assignment.  These are columns G and K.  It's also how the credits for the 4th group are calculated in column O.  The formulas are:

```
G3:  =C3-E3
K3:  =G3-I3
O3:  =K3-M3
```

Again, you can enter the formula in G3 and then copy it to K3 and O3.

**Credits for Groups**

The credits for groups 1-3 are calculated as follows.  If the (remaining) cumulative credits for the preceding course were more than 1/4 of the total, it means that the current course must be in the next group, so zero credits are assigned.  Otherwise, what is assigned is the minimum of the actual course credit or the amount needed to reach the 1/4 total.  The formulas are:

```
E3:  =IF(D2>$C$21,0,MIN(C3,$C$21-D2))
I3:  =IF(H2>$C$21,0,MIN(G3,$C$21-H2))
M3:  =IF(L2>$C$21,0,MIN(K3,$C$21-L2))
```

You can enter the E3 formula and then copy it to I3 and M3.

**Weights**

The weights compare the course credit assigned to the group against the 1/4 total.  These formulas are:

```
F3:  =E3/$C$21
J3:  =I3/$C$21
N3:  =M3/$C$21
P3:  =O3/$C$21
```

You can enter the F3 formula and then copy it to J3, N3, and P3.

**Group Averages**

The group averages are the SUMPRODUCT of the Grade and relevant weight columns.  These formulas are:

```
E21:  =SUMPRODUCT($B3:$B20,F3:F20)
I21:  =SUMPRODUCT($B3:$B20,J3:J20)
M21:  =SUMPRODUCT($B3:$B20,N3:N20)
O21:  =SUMPRODUCT($B3:$B20,P3:P20)
```

You can enter the E21 formula and then copy it to I21, M21, and O21.

Once you have this set up in a generic form, you can use it like a template without having to re-enter formulas.  Just copy the template to another worksheet and input new course data.

#### Making it prettier

As mentioned earlier, you can hide the helper columns and suppress the zero values.  You can also "hide" values in rows that have been pre-populated with formulas but do not have course information.  That's done by wrapping the formulas in the Group and Weight columns with an IF test.

Assuming that when you add rows for additional courses, the Credits column will be the last value to be entered, we can check whether it's blank, and show a null (""), if so, in the calculated columns instead of the formulas above.  Wrap the formulas like this: `=IF(ISBLANK($C3),"",formula_above).  So, for example, the Group 1 columns become:

```
E3:  =IF(ISBLANK($C3),"",IF(D2>$C$20,0,MIN(C3,$C$20-D2)))
F3:  =IF(ISBLANK($C3),"",E3/$C$20)
```

In the screenshot below, I pre-populated rows 3-20 with formulas and suppress them as above (the hidden helper columns don't need to be suppressed).

[image: screenshot 3]

Notice that I added course 10 (just course name, grade, and credit).  The calculated values appear for the row, the groups are adjusted for the additional data, and the averages reflect the additional course.  I did the example in LibreOffice Calc, which doesn't have the feature of suppressing zero values (AFAIK), so I wasn't able to illustrate an example completely gussied up.

Comment: Thank you fixer1234 - a clear, comprehensive, and elegant-enough-for-my-purposes answer. Thank you for taking the time to outline the solution in such detail and so clearly. I'm truly grateful!